# What are the differences mark-ring and global-mark-ring?

Tags: mark, mark-ring

I have just explore how to use mark rings in emacs.

There are two kind of mark type `mark-ring` and  `global-mark-ring`.

What are the differences between them and is there any option to push all marks to global to reaching from everywhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should pose only one question per question here.

1. For your first question: *What are the differences between the `mark-ring` and the `global-mark-ring`:

   This is answered very well in the Emacs manual, nodes [Mark Ring](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Mark-Ring.html) and [Global Mark Ring](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Global-Mark-Ring.html).

   You really owe it to yourself to learn to ***ask Emacs***: `C-h r` is your starting point.

   From node **Global Mark Ring**:

   > In addition to the ordinary mark ring that *belongs to each buffer*, Emacs
   >   has a *single* "**global mark ring**".
   >
   > Each time you set a mark, this is
   >   recorded in the global mark ring in addition to the current buffer’s own
   >   mark ring, ***if you have switched buffers since the previous mark setting.***
   >
   > Hence, the global mark ring records a sequence of ***buffers that you have
   >   been in***, and, for each buffer, *a place* where you set the mark.  The
   >   length of the global mark ring is controlled by `global-mark-ring-max`,
   >   and is 16 by default.

   If there is something unclear about that then please refine your question or pose another one.
2. Your second question is unclear to me: *Is there any option to push all marks to global to reaching from everywhere?*

   Are you asking whether the `global-mark-ring` could just include all marks from all buffers?  If so, the answer is no, there is no such option.

   However, if you use [Icicles](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) then you have command **`icicle-goto-any-marker`**, which does let you go to any marker from any buffer.  It is bound to **`C-0 C-SPC`**. (Perhaps Helm has something similar?) You also have commands `icicle-goto-marker`, bound to **`C-- C-SPC`**, and `icicle-goto-global-marker`, bound to **`C-- C-x C-SPC`**, which let you navigate among only markers in a given buffer or only global markers, respectively.

   > **`icicle-goto-any-marker`** is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
   >   [`icicles-cmd2.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/icicles-cmd2.el).
   >
   > It is bound to `menu-bar search goto icicles icicle-goto-any-marker`.
   >
   > `(icicle-goto-any-marker)`
   >
   > Like `icicle-goto-marker`, but lets you visit markers in all buffers.
   >   If user option **`icicle-show-multi-completion-flag`** is non-nil, then
   >   each completion candidate is has two parts, the first of which is the
   >   name of the marker's buffer, and the second of which is the text from
   >   the marker's line.
   >
   > By default, candidates are sorted in buffer order and then marker
   >   order, that is, buffer positions.  Use `C-M-,` or `C-,` to change the
   >   sort order.  Remember too that you can use `C-A` to toggle
   >   case-sensitivity (e.g., for buffer names).
   >
   > See also command `icicle-goto-global-marker`.

Comment: Someone care to explain the downvote 7 years later?